# alert and function call within function happening out of order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a pen that uses the navigator.geolocation function to get the longitude and latitude of the user. That much is working fine.

My issue is when I call the `getWeatherInfo()` function. You will see that the first line in that function calls another function `getLocation()`, then raises an `alert` - `alert(location)` in this case. However, I don't understand why that alert is raised before the function call to `getLocation()` takes place, since `var location = getLocation();` function is called before `alert(location)`? I believe this is the case since there is an `alert(lat + " " + lon);' in the`getLocation()` function and that alert comes up second.

So, not sure what is going on there.. This is probably related to why I am not getting back a result into `var location = getLocation();` which shows up as undefined ???

[Link to my pen](https://codepen.io/DarrenHaynes/pen/cb48b73814e2bc96526f39fc8799bb1f)

Here is the code also:

HTML:

```
<div id="data">
</div>

<button onclick="getWeatherInfo()">Click Me</button>
```

CSS:

```
#data {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: purple;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Javascript:

```
function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var lat = (Math.round(position.coords.latitude)).toString();
      var lon = (Math.round(position.coords.longitude)).toString();
      alert(lat + " " + lon); 
      return [lat, lon];
    });
  } else {
    alert("You must allow geolocation to retrieve weather data for your area");
  }
}

function getWeatherInfo() {
  var location = getLocation();
  alert(location); 
  $("#data").html(location[0] + " " + location[1]);
}
```

Note that jQuery is enabled and used in this pen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to grab the data but I see what you mean by calling out of order.. Try putting this line right by your alert within the function..

```
$("#data").html(location[0] + " " + location[1]);
```

That's probably not how you want to arrange you code though is it.. You'll have to set it up something like so:

```
function getLocation(callback) {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var lat = (Math.round(position.coords.latitude)).toString();
      var lon = (Math.round(position.coords.longitude)).toString();
      //alert(lat + " " + lon); 
      var coords = [lat, lon];
      callback(coords);
      //return coords;
    });
  } else {
    alert("You must allow geolocation to retrieve weather data for your area");
  }
}

function getWeatherInfo() {
    getLocation(function(location){
        //alert(location); 
        $("#data").html(location[0] + " " + location[1]);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's because `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` is running asynchronously, therefore the `alert(location)` is invoked immediately after invoking `getLocation()` and not waiting for it to resolve. You have to use a Promise or a callback to work with your recieved location.

Note: You should use `console.log` for debugging.

Edit: Look at @Rick's answer for a callback example.

Comment: Thank you. Maybe codepen works differently, but console.log doesn't see to do anything for me.

Comment: Open the developer tools of your browser (usally by pressing "F12"). There you will find a console tab which shows the output of console.log